# Error with homepage on Firefox (Linux)

Tags: linux, firefox

I'm using Firefox browser v106 on Linux (Debian distribution on amd64).

My settings use "**Firefox Home**" (Web Search and Shortcuts) as **Homepage**. When I try to open a new page or tab, I have an error : "Oops, something went wrong loading this content. Refresh page to try again".

Despite my research, impossible to fix this issue. In Web Developer Tools / Console, I have the log : `TypeError : sectionOrder is undefined`, in file `resource://activity-stream/data/content/activity-stream.bundle.js`

Have you any clue to fix this issue without resetting my Firefox profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue : `about:support` => Clear startup cache...

Firefox will restart and my problem is gone (homepage is OK with Web Search and Shortcuts) :)